# Remove set of rows if column values decrease anywhere

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to remove set of rows based on values in specific columns, that decrease in at any point. Please assume there are more rows and columns in the dataframe:

```
date     var       col_a    col_b    col_c ... 
1/02/20  id_1      3        0        1
1/03/20  id_1      4        1        1
1/04/20  id_1      3        1        2
1/02/20  id_2      0        0        0
1/03/20  id_2      1        2        0
1/04/20  id_2      1        2        0
.
.
.
```

So because for `id_1`, `col_a` decreases from 3->4->3, I would like to return this:

```
date     var       col_a    col_b    col_c ... 
1/02/20  id_2      0        0        0
1/03/20  id_2      1        2        0
1/04/20  id_2      1        2        0
.
.
.
```

So the values can increase and then decrease, but at any point if there is a decrease, I would like to remove that entire set of rows for `var`. I was looking into `is_monotonic` to find if the columns are increasing/decreasing, but not sure how to combine that would a groupby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
s = (df.iloc[:,1:]
   .groupby('var').diff()
   .lt(0).any(1)
   .groupby(df['var']).transform('max')
)

df[~s]
```

Output:

```
      date   var  col_a  col_b  col_c
3  1/02/20  id_2      0      0      0
4  1/03/20  id_2      1      2      0
5  1/04/20  id_2      1      2      0
```

Comment: I want to be able to select these columns by name by passing in a list, not by index.

Comment: Another issue with this is if you take diff across and entire column and `var` changes, you'll get negatives on the first row of the next `var` which causes everything to be removed

Comment: No, you get `nan` in the first row, and `nan < 0` is `False`.